# Ordering a drink, conversational Japanese

Tags: orthography

**Disclaimer**: *This relates to prose, I would never consider being intentionally rude in real life.*

I'm currently writing a short-story, and in it there's a scene in a Japanese restaurant. It calls for one of the characters (female) to call the waiter over and request a bottle of Sake (nihonshu?), as per the chef's recommendation.

My own—slow but ongoing—study of Japanese, is of little help, because text-books has an awful tendency to mangle the politeness in these matters.  From what I understand of the politeness customs in Japan, a customer would probably **not** be more polite toward the staff, than the staff toward the customer.

So, how would one, as a woman, in conversational Japanese, bordering on being downright rude, order a bottle of the house's recommended rice-wine?

My own best guess would be "*Oi, nihonshu kudasai!*", but that doesn't sound right to me…

Comment: Who taught you to use　おい like that?  That is out of the question!  It is far worse than "bordering on being downright rude".

Comment: おい, which is commonly romanized as "oi", is rude, not bordering on it. Also, it seems a bit odd to combine it with "kudasai", which is polite. My best take on "bordering on rude" would be to just use non-polite language, e.g. "osusume no nihonshu mottekite!" or "osusume no nihonshu chōdai!".

Comment: @TokyoNagoya It's been so long I can't even remember. And yes I'm aware just how rude it is, but for the character it actually rather fits. She's a _deceptively crude_ lady, if that makes sense.

Comment: @dainichi I suppose mixing the two could be considered odd, but people often are, odd I mean. Consider two american males conversing, going from "You pigfaced sack of shit" to "please" in the same sentence wouldn't be unthinkable. I think this combination makes her sound more crude than rude though, no? I do like your suggestions though.

Comment: @xles, I agree. There are definitely situations where your combination is possible, e.g. if "kudasai" is said in a very sarcastic tone, or the speaker said the sentence previously without the "oi" and is sorta quoting themself: "Please bring me sake.... HEY!!! (I said) PLEASE BRING ME SAKE!!!". But the situations are a bit special, and I just wanted to make sure people were aware of that.

Comment: Addressing a male waiter as お兄ちゃん would be another example of bordering-on-rude (situation-dependent).  Although personally I think doing this at all is a bad idea.  Unless the phrase is short and obvious (like foreign-language expletives), you will then have to translate/explain what is going on and it actually doesn't add anything compared to just stating that she orders a bottle of sake in rather blunt Japanese and the waiter/someone at the next table gives her a dirty look for being uncouth.

Comment: @nkjt Totally fair and valid point, there's no real good reason for me to explicitly writing it out in text, aside from a general desire to do so.  It's a first person perspective narrative from the point-of-view of another character out to dine with the aforementioned woman.  So the main character wont understand what's going on either which way I do it.

Comment: I think ordering a drink like juice, beer, coffee etc is simple (eg すいません、オレンジジュースください。/ ちょっと、コーヒーちょうだい。) but it seems like ordering sake is not that simple... http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11109854891 http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1421463769

Comment: Maybe ちょっと、日本酒ちょうだい。 or ちょっと。熱燗/一本つけて。???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @dainichi has suggested in his comment I think you could use

> ちょっと。おススメのお酒/日本酒ちょうだい。or
>   ちょっと。おススメのお酒/日本酒持ってきて。or
>   ちょっと。おススメのお酒/日本酒もらうわ。

etc. in a Japanese restaurant. If in [居酒屋]{いざかや} you would say

> [熱燗]{あつかん}つけて。
>   一本つけて。
>   [沢の鶴]{さわのつる}、[冷]{ひや}で。

etc., depending on what (type/brand) you want / how (hot/iced/warm/room temperature) you want it.

Answer (score -1):

Say "ano"　or "chotto" to get attention at beginning, both is polite.(Oi is really rude)
And the rest is just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't say that あの or ちょっと is particularly polite.

Answer (score -2):

Simply: お酒を一本下さい。

Be careful, though, it means you want one bottle of rice wine.

PS. It's just a deduction I came to personally, but the tidbit you wrote makes me recall all the situations I stumbled upon when drunken people, outsiders of course, kept on insulting the Japanese. It sounds like "Bring me some booze, would ya!?". Just be careful when they're getting "edgy" with their opinions on gaijins, because on many occasions, they have a reason to.

Comment: Duly noted, and that does sound like it might be exactly what I want here.  I should probably put a disclaimer in the question that I personally has more common sense than that, and would never be this rude in person...  But that's why we have prose, to escape reality and do things we wouldn't do in real life.  (Love the username by the way, fooo!)

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for, though. 

You can alternatively try お酒を一本頂戴, but that's as far as you can get with being humble. I also think 頂戴 is the more feminine word. You mustn't use keigo words to describe your own actions.

For future reference, please try these:
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%B7%E6%80%A7%E8%AA%9E - Masculine language
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E6%80%A7%E8%AA%9E - Feminine language